# Verifying that Mockito.when calls are still needed

Tags: java, mockito

Over time, our tests have collected a whole bunch of Mockito.when calls. I'd like to know if there some that aren't needed any more. I tried doing

```
Mockito.verify(Mockito.when(someMock.someCall().return("foo").getMock(), Mockito.atLeastOnce());
```

But get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'd like to aspect in a way to check if these when()s are being used as there are far too many for a human to do by hand, so trying to get to figure out how to do this inline.

I could just duplicate the same call found in when() with a completely separate call to Mockito.verify(), but it is hard duplicate the when() call method and arguments call chain through aspects.

Comment: Use [strict stubbing](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-unnecessary-stubbing-exception).

Comment: You could try `verifyZeroInteractions` . Though I would say if you have so many `when`s then your units/classes have to many responsibilities.

Comment: thanks @Turing85, that seems to do what i want. post an answer and i'll checkmark you, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in solution to the problem would be to use strict stubbing. There is [an article over at Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-unnecessary-stubbing-exception) explaining it.